# "Until Monday" includes Monday or Excludes Monday?

Tags: prepositions

When saying simply "**until**" it includes or excludes what mentioned after it?

For example:

> You should make registration **until** Monday.
>
> "It's best to avoid full-body bathing **until** the second day after
>   surgery"

Comment: this is a very common question read this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/is-until-inclusive-or-exclusive basically the word until is very problematic and as a native speaker I am often unsure, so never ever use it

Comment: Your first example is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are different, as the second one is a negative, but it is clear from

> It's best to avoid full-body bathing **until** the second day after surgery.

that "**until**" means you can bathe from the second day. In which case this will mean the same

> It's best to avoid full-body bathing **before** the second day after surgery.

The first case is more tricky

> You should make registration **until** Monday.

I would assume this means that registration on Monday is allowed, if not then I would write

> You should make registration **before** Monday.

So whether **until** is inclusive or not, depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

The second one first:

> "It's best to avoid full-body bathing until the second day after surgery"

This means you can start bathing on the second day.

The first one is problematic.

> *You should make registration until Monday.*

This one doesn't work, any way you slice it.

For starters, I wouldn't say 'make registration'. Just use the verb 'register'.

Also, 'until' doesn't work in this case, because the act of registering is a one-time thing. So I think you should go with either 'by' or 'no later than' instead:

> *You should register **by/no later than** Monday.*

Or better yet:

> *The registration deadline is Monday.*

Comment: If the meaning of the second sentence is "This means you can start bathing on the second day." So why in this site is written: "It's best to avoid full-body bathing until the second day after surgery, but sponge bathing is fine. **After the second day, you can bathe your baby** or toddler as normal; with newborns, you should wait until the umbilical cord has fallen off, at about two weeks. Avoid very warm water." It seems that this doesn't agree with you. Isn't it? https://www.ucsfbenioffchildrens.org/education/post-circumcision_care_for_newborns_babies_and_toddlers/

Comment: @Wittyloquacity When I said "This means you can start bathing on the second day", I meant "you can start full-body bathing", just as I think you meant the same when you said in your answer "that "until" means you can bathe from the second day." Or didn't you?

Comment: @Wittyloquacity BTW, the OP's first sentence is ungrammatical, just so you know.