# Until "X" Day Means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a paragraph:

> The next stage in the re-development of the roads in the town of Gatton will mean that Main Street will be closed between Little and Denning Streets from 6am on Saturday, 12 August to 6pm on Sunday, 13 August. The intersections of these streets with Main Street will not be affected. We expect that the work will be completed at this time without further disruption to traffic. Motorists should note that Main Street will be closed over the weekend during the hours indicated.

Please check the validity of the below sentence:

> The road will be closed for two days and **not re-opened until** Monday.

Does not it mean the road will be closed for Saturday and Sunday and will open on Monday? I answered "true," indicating these two days against a related question but it came out wrong. Can somebody explain why am I wrong on this?

I am looking for a "true," "false," or "not given" answer.

Comment: This question may have answers that will help: [Is “until” inclusive or exclusive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/33340/9161)

Comment: "Re-opened" should not be hyphenated. It is "reopened." As far as your question, I agree with you. I would expect the road to be open on Monday, at some time. Could you post a link to the related question you're talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer was wrong because according to the information in the paragraph, the road reopens on Sunday-- not Monday. It is a true or false question. You should have chosen "false."

As far as my comment about not hyphenating "reopened." I was wrong in this case. I didn't have the original sentence. Normally, reopened is not hyphenated, but they hyphenated it because it was at the end of a line.