# The meaning of "until next Thursday"

Tags: word-usage

Imagine a situation in which you go to your favorite bakery. Then, a sign that says "We will be closed until next Thursday." In this situation, when do you think you can visit the bakery?

Next Thursday or next Friday?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "until" inclusive or exclusive?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33340/is-until-inclusive-or-exclusive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take that to mean I could buy bread there on Thursday, but I would probably call ahead first. I would want them to say

> We will be closed through next Wednesday. We  hope to see  you
> Thursday morning.

Comment: In British English, I would expect "We will be reopening on Thursday" (but I would understand 'closed until Thursday' to mean the same thing).